# how can I implement non-rectangular shapes for buttons in android

Tags: android

hi i have to realize this layout . it has this layout.  [image: inactive buttons]

I could try to use the icons as imagebuttons but the active state of a button is somewhat like this one !

[image: one button has been pressed]

How should i proceed with this ?

Comment: That's too much of a question to give you one answer. The buttons on top are quite easy positioned `ImageButton`s. Tricky is the circle in the middle. You can create `ImageButton`s for each part and position them programmatically around the circle, but the clickable areas will overlap. So I think the best way is to make the whole circle with all buttons clickable and have a touch listener that detects whicht part of the circle was actually clicked. Maybe you can simplify and focus your question around that specific part. BTW: Nice design!

Comment: @jboi you got it 100%.
will I be bale to show both states of each button using the touch listner method? Any eaxample ?

Comment: For the different states of drawables you can use `selector` or `LevelListDrawable`. With them you define the different bitmaps for touched and untouched state at different levels. With `ImageView.setLevel(...)` you set the level at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `selector` as follows:

1. Prepare 2 images for button states, and put it into `res/drawable` folder.

   button_normal_green.png – Default image button.

   button_pressed_yellow.png – Display when button is pressed.
2. Now, create a new XML file in “res/drawable/” folder, in whatever name you want, in this case, we just give a name as “new_button.xml“. This file defined which button state is belong to which image.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow" android:state_pressed="true" />

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
     </selector>
   ```

3.set background to button

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/new_button" />
```

Have a look at [Complete Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/)

Comment: thanks, my actual problem is the shape of buttons , if i use rectangular shapes either i have to either leave some part of the buttons to be unclickable or they will overlap

Comment: How can selector help buttons to be non-rectangular?