# Touch bounds for custom buttons in a circle menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I'll need to implement a UI that reflects the layout of a real object. Below is the layout that the client wants. Each black block is a button, so it need a custom `drawable`, `listener`s, `state`s, etc.

I'd like to use a custom implementation of the `Button` widget, but as far as I know they only accept rectangular touch targets and laying them out could be tricky.

[image]

What would you use to achieve this layout?
Please note: the 2 central button should be a semicircle cutted in half (with some padding between the 2), not this strange shieldy shape, I'm just not that good with Photoshop.

EDIT: As suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475368/how-can-i-implement-non-rectangular-shapes-for-buttons-in-android) I could use a `TouchListener` on the layout and fake a click on the right button. The main problem with this solution is that I'll need to know the bounds of the drawable, not the rectangular ones of the button's bounding box (that is always rectangular). How could I do that?

Comment: The solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475368/how-can-i-implement-non-rectangular-shapes-for-buttons-in-android

Comment: so what do you want? ready layout with this buttons?

Comment: An hint at what I could use. If it is possible to have non rectangular touch target for a Button. You know, some help, as for the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Foxinsocks I'll try with the overlaying touch listener, I'll just need to figure out how to understand the bounds of the buttons.

Comment: I'll try with a RelativeLayout containing some TextViews or ImageViews (which are clickable controls). Relatively positioned over the background image. It does really no matter, if they are "square" controls. You typically touch the clickable areas inside, not on the corners or on the sides. So, the "square" approximation is good enough.